# Как извлечь массив из строки?

Tags: php

Есть строка вида
Array( [order] => Array([id] = > 1 [fake] => false))
Извлечена из БД, где хранится в виде строки, как её перевести в массив? explode, implode и преобразование в массив нужного результата не выдаёт.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: спросите у того, кто ее в БД в таком виде записал.

Comment: я понимаю, что json был бы более логичным решением, но хранение осуществляет внешний сервис, они не будут ради меня переписывать свою логику

Comment: логичных способов тонну найти можно, serialize, json, xml, csv, текст по строкам, что угодно. В других полях БД оно случаем не хранится? Или может быть данная структура массива всегда такая. и не может иметь других полей или вложенностей. Тогда проще регулярками выдернуть. зы: что за сервис такой сторонний?

Comment: яндекс.маркет так хранит логи обмена данными в модуле на сайте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мотороллер не мой, я просто разместил объяву:

```
function text_to_array($str) {

    //Initialize arrays
    $keys = array();
    $values = array();
    $output = array();
    
    //Is it an array?
    if( substr($str, 0, 5) == 'Array' ) {
    
        //Let's parse it (hopefully it won't clash)
        $array_contents = substr($str, 7, -2);
        $array_contents = str_replace(array(' ', '[', ']', '=>'), array('', '#!#', '#?#', ''), $array_contents);
        $array_fields = explode("#!#", $array_contents);
        
        //For each array-field, we need to explode on the delimiters I've set and make it look funny.
        for($i = 0; $i < count($array_fields); $i++ ) {
        
            //First run is glitched, so let's pass on that one.
            if( $i != 0 ) {
            
                $bits = explode('#?#', $array_fields[$i]);
                if( $bits[0] != '' ) $output[$bits[0]] = $bits[1];
            
            }
        }
        
        //Return the output.
        return $output;
        
    } else {
        
        //Duh, not an array.
        echo 'The given parameter is not an array.';
        return null;
    }
    
}
```

Если скормить

```
$array_string = <<<TEST
Array
(
    [foo] => bar
    [bar] => foo
    [foobar] => barfoo

)   
TEST;   


$result = text_to_array($array_string);
```

то в `$result` будет нужный массив.

---

Ещё две функции:

https://gist.github.com/llagerlof/fc2031024c0563bc69d76dd2a1fbcb4c

---

Однако стоит заметить, что данный вид хранения весьма специфичен (читай как неприемлем в сообществе разработчиков-профессионалов),поэтому стОит подумать над правильным решением хранения данных

Comment: чую, если строки внутри будут содережать что-то из алфавита `[]=>` то закончится все печально, или нет?

Comment: @teran см. первую строку ответа :)))

Comment: видел ) странно, что оно вообще без рекурсии

Comment: @teran там по ссылке есть с рекурсиями. Возможно текущая и не работает со вложенкой.

Comment: спасибо, функция с рекурсией из гитхаба помогла